# Como enviar variables desde Ajax Jquery a php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Muy Buenas. Les describo mi problema

Tengo una tabla la cual contiene un botón con un valor = Id de un contacto (El Id varia según la fila en la que nos ubiquemos). cabe destacar que todo esto esta dentro de un formulario llamado frm_ContactosLista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es enviar dicho valor del boton seleccionado por medio de una petición ajax y recibirla en un documento php para procesarlo.

EL codigo de la solicitud es el siguiente

```html
$("button[name='btn_Mcontactos']").click(function(){
              var valor = $(this).val();
              var url = "./webservice/llenarcontactos.php";

              $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: $("#frm_ContactosLista").serialize(),
                  success: function(data){
                      $("#resultado").html(data);
                  }
              });




              return false;
          });
```

el codigo HTML del formulario

```html
<form class='form form-horizontal validate-form' style='margin-bottom: 0;' method="post" id="frm_ContactosLista">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Contactos" data-whatever="@mdo">+ Nuevo Contacto</button>
  <!-- tabla -->
  <div class="" id=resultado>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
      <div class='box-content box-no-padding'>
        <div class='responsive-table'>
          <div class='scrollable-area'>
            <table class='data-table table table-bordered table-striped' data-pagination-records='25' style='padding-left:3px;'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width:55px">
                    Editar
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    ID
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Nombre
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Titulo
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    compania
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Telefono
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Email
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {{if ListaContactos}}
              <tbody>
                {{foreach ListaContactos}}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btnimg" name="btn_Mcontactos" id="btn_Mcontactos" value="{{contactoId}}">
                                                                      <img src="public/img/carpeta.png" alt="Ver" style="height:25px; width:25px;" />
                                                                  </button>

                  </td>
                  <td> {{contactoId}}</td>
                  <td> {{nombre}}</td>
                  <td> {{titulo}}</td>
                  <td> {{compania}}</td>
                  <td> {{telefono}}</td>
                  <td> {{email}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{endfor ListaContactos}}
              </tbody>
              {{endif ListaContactos}}
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br><br>
</form>
```

y este es el codigo del archivo llenarcontactos.php donde deberia recibir el codigo

```html
 <?php
    require_once("../api/callapi.php");
    echo "<script>alert('Aqui deberia mostrar el codigo');</script>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que agregar la variable al serialize:

```
$("#frm_ContactosLista").serialize() + '&id='+valor ,
```

Comment: Gracias amigo  funciono